# Return all customers with order status 'Awaiting return' and how many days since most recent orders

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables one storing customer details

`Customers` table columns:

```
CID, Name, DoB,
```

`Orders` table:

```
ID, CID, orderStatus, OrderDate, ReOrderDate
```

I will need to return customers whose `orderStatus` is 'Awaiting return' and how many days from most recent order. I have two columns with `datetime` type `orderDate` and `ReOrderDate`. I want to first check which one is more recent then use it to calculate how many days from that date to today's date.

```
SELECT
    c.CID, c.name, o.orderStatus, 
    (Not sure how to return number of days)
FROM
    customers c
LEFT JOIN 
    orders o ON c.CID = o.Oid
WHERE
    o.orderStatus = 'Awaiting return'
```

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Also add a tag for the dbms used. (Especially important when date/time is involved, since many product are far from ANSI SQL compliant in that area.)

Comment: Why do you want a LEFT JOIN?

Comment: @jarlh I have added sql server 2012 management studio tag I am using that one. left join to return all customers table information

Comment: But you wrote '_need to return customers whose orderStatus is 'Awaiting return'_', not _all customers_. This is why a [mcve] is important, to clarify contradictions.

Answer (score -2):

```
Select c.CID, c.name, o.orderStatus, 
    CASE WHEN o.OrderDate >= o.ReOrderDate 
    THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, o.OrderDate, GETDATE())
    ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, o.ReOrderDate,GETDATE())
    END AS 'No. Days'
from customers c

   join orders o
     on c.CID = o.Oid

where o.orderStatus = 'Awaiting return'
```

This will look and see what date is greater first and then do the calculation based on the greatest date. Just know that this returns a row for every order that has that status. So there is no aggregation for the total number of orders. Or the order they have been waiting the longest on.

I also changed the `left join`. To a `inner join` because you specify in the question that you only want customers that have orders in this status.

Comment: Because of the where-clause (`o.orderStatus = 'Awaiting return'`) you will always find an order,  so you should do `INNER JOIN`, and not `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: The second and third parameter to `DATEDIFF` seem to be in wrong order, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/4fYgs4uq

Comment: You are right. I will make these changes.